# generating captcha

Tags: android, captcha

Does anyone know if there is any library available for generating captcha which is possible to implement in android application so the captcha appears in the activity?

Thank you.

Comment: out of curiosity, why? 
Afraid a robot will be using the phone instead of a user?

Comment: @Dinedal: "it will use whatever backend you have" - that is why you need to provide captcha challenge in order to stop the bots...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe the open source JCaptcha from http://jcaptcha.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

yeah it is simple to implement the technique of capcha in android or in any other plateform . what you have to do is to put some images into the drawable , put an ImageView right above you EditView and linked those images with an Array or any collection in which you saved the correct text of the images ... then on button click get the ID for the random image and verify it with the saved collection of text .

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [recaptcha](http://recaptcha.net)?

Comment: how we can use it for android ??